# Programming tools for client and server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I would like to develop ASP.net MVC projects from multiple computers. We are facing the problem to combine files from multiple computer.Is there any tools or suggestion to update or upload the new or modified files in one computer's project as server computer? If any confusion please ask me.

Comment: Sounds like you need a version control system.

Comment: You should look into GIT and TFS for version control. They both word with Visual Studio.